# Is there a way to run Elasticsearch and Kibana behind the scenes (hidden) via windows cmd?

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, batch-file, kibana, windows-server-2012-r2

Currently I'm running Elasticsearch and Kibana in their own console windows. I don't want these console windows to be able to be seen, some users should not be able to be able to view these windows. I wanted to run them in Docker containers, but docker is not compatible with windows server 2012 r2.  Would it be possible to create a .bat file to launch Kibana and Elasticsearch, then execute the created .bat file from PowerShell hidden? I have no experience in PowerShell and would prefer a different approach if possible.

Comment: It is in the documentation, these are the [steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html#windows-service) to run elasticsearch as a service in Windows. For Kibana you will need to create a service, you can use something like NSSM to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the documentation, these are the steps to run elasticsearch as a service in Windows. For Kibana you will need to create a service, you can use something like NSSM to do that. –
leandrojmp
1 hour ago